# Change the css class of the href (<a>-tag) inside a thumbnail by php in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

[image: The images is showing hos i want i to look like, today the href only has the thumbnail-link class and i want to add the class called. video_post_play-button-overlay.]

I am working on a WordPress website and need to manipulate the HTML by using a PHP snippet. Specifically, I need to add, replace, or change a certain class. My current code is able to locate the specific post but not retrieve its CSS class, and I am unable to change it. How can I accomplish this?

```php
function add_video_symbol3($containsVideo, $postId) { 

    if ($containsVideo === '1'){    
            
       //replace-method does not work
       //$thumbnail_html_with_class = str_replace('class="thumbnail-link', 'class="thumbnail-link video_post_play-button-overlay', $thumbnail_html);         
    
    return  $containsVideo;
      }
    }
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'add_video_symbol', 10, 2);

// Set up the query to retrieve all posts
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'post',  // Replace with your post type if necessary
     'posts_per_page' => -1, // Retrieve all posts
    );
$query = new WP_Query($args);

// Check if there are any posts
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    // Loop through each post
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
       
        // Get the value of a specific custom field (e.g., 'contains_video')
        $containsVideo = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'contains_video', true);
        $postId = get_the_ID();
        
        $filter_val = apply_filters('post_thumbnail_html', $containsVideo, $postId);
    }
    // Restore the global post data
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    echo 'No posts found';
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to replace, what class? can you give in your question an HTML code output sample for that?

Comment: div class="article-thumbnail"> <div class="thumbnail thumbnail--full" style="background-image: url(ht website.eu/app/uploads/2023/06/indy-farg.png)"> <a href="#" class="thumbnail-link <div class="article_badge"> </div > flex </div> </div>== $0. Today the link contains a class called thumbnail-link and i want to add a class called video_post_play-button-overlay

Comment: Edit/Update your question carefully please, with all required detail, explanations and screenshots, if you want to have a chance to get helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation of the [post_thumbnail_html](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_thumbnail_html/) filter, then you'll see that the first parameter is supposed to be a string of HTML. When using `apply_filters` with existing filters, make absolutely sure that arguments match the specification.

In your case you don't need the loop to modify the output as the `post_thumbnail_html` filter will run on every call of [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) and will also provide the `$post_id` by default. Place all your logic in the filter callback and make sure to return the `$html` variable at the end.

```php
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', function($html, $post_id) {
  $contains_video = get_post_meta($post_id, 'contains_video', true);

  if ($contains_video === '1') {
    $html = str_replace('class="thumbnail-link', 'class="thumbnail-link video_post_play-button-overlay', $html);
  }

  return $html;
}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, could i just ask you how you recommend me to retrieve the $html and $post_id. I am not very used to php so i may miss something.

Comment: You don't have to retrieve anything. If you look at the source code of [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/#source) then you see that at the bottom the `post_thumbnail_html` filter is applied. The HTML that the `get_the_post_thumbnail` function generates is passed to the filter so that you can modify the output of the HTML. Same with `$post_id`. Filters are WordPress feature and are there to give you the power to modify output based on your liking. [See this article for examples.](https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/filter/)

Comment: Alright, because i tried your code and i never enter the function so nothing happens, do i need to call it somehow?

Comment: You need to call `get_the_post_thumbnail()` or `the_post_thumbnail()` in your template. That in turn should run the code in the filter of the snippet.

Comment: would you like to give me an example on how i can write that?

Comment: I'm confused. Maybe you should look into how the actual HTML is being processed in your PHP templates. I was assuming you're using `the_post_thumbnail()` or a derivative of it in your templates to output your thumbnail HTML. I think it's a good idea that you include the PHP which is responsible for creating the HTML in the first place.